# dual y axis plotting causes data points looks messy at left corner of chart

Tags: mpandroidchart

i am using MPAndroid charting toolkit for data visualization. chart plotting smooth in MPAndroid but problem arise when i try plot dual y axis(left& right). As right axis appear data points on spread over the x axis completely. all data points appearing on the left of chart. How can i spread the data points ?

```
mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.Chart);
mChart.setGridBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F4F4F4"));
mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
mChart.setHighlightEnabled(false);


mChart.setDragEnabled(false);
mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
mChart.setPinchZoom(true);
mChart.setDescription("");
mChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaxValue(YMaxValue);
mChart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinValue(YMinValue);
mChart.getAxisLeft().setStartAtZero(false);
mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
if(General.InnerClass.Y2AxisValues.size()>0)
{
 mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(true);
 mChart.getAxisRight().setSpaceBottom(12.25f);
 mChart.getAxisRight().setAxisMaxValue(Y2MaxValue);
 mChart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinValue(Y2MinValue);
 mChart.getAxisRight().setStartAtZero(false);
 mChart.getXAxis().setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
}
mChart.setData(data);
progbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mChart.invalidate();
```

**Before**
[image]

**After**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while plotting y2 axis providing the x values is the problem. values for the x axis should be provide for single time. providing twice add the values to x axis exiting values get doubled.

thnx @philipp

Answer (score 0):

**The data points are exactly where they should be.** The only thing that has changed is the range of values that is displayed on each axis.
--> this range is now significationly lower because only one set of data is represented by each axis, before, one axis had to scale large enough to display both datasets.

I suggest you read the [documentation of the YAxis](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis-%28YLabels%29) and simply increase the range of values that should be displayed on the axis.

Comment: @Phillip  as you can see in my code given above that i am providing custom range for the each axis. This range provided on the behalf of actual data. so whenever chart data get changed i am providing the new range according to data. but chart data point not spreading over the x axis. why all of them appearing only in left of the chart. even scale also not start from the given min value. in above given image i am providing the min value 1240 and the max value 1440 to right axis and i want the interval of the data should be 40 but axis value not starting from the given value.can see in 2nd image

Comment: can you please look into it @philipp-jahoda.